# Best way to Compare DateTime to trigger code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

What is the best way to compare two `DateTime` in a specific format and trigger code if `DateTime` has passed.

My DateTime is formatted as `4/26/2017 10:00:00 AM`

```
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime eventDateTime = DateTime.Parse("4/26/2017 10:00:00 AM");

int result = DateTime.Compare(currentDateTime, eventDateTime);

if (result < 0)
    Response.Write( "is earlier than Do Nothing");
else if (result == 0)
    Response.Write("is the same time as: Do Nothing");         
else
    Response.Write("Time is greater, Trigger Action ");
```

Is the above code fine for comparison or we can improve it.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I don't think there's a more efficiant way of doing this.

Comment: If you use it more often, you should put it into an extra class and return an enum or something like that for readability purposes, I cannot think of any better way either. The strategy pattern is way too oversized for this situation I guess.

Comment: Be certain that the inbound event `DateTime` is in the same timezone/locale as the server time, or convert both to UTC reliably. Most often we convert to UTC on client (mobile or web), then all dates on server UTC also, to ensure fidelity. `DateTime.Now` can cause a lot of unforeseen headaches otherwise.

Comment: @MarkLarter, My `currentDateTime` date are for specific timezone as i have localized, It is good point you mentioned as web server on which this code is running has different timezone. +1

Comment: Write your code for readability. Make sure it works. Only if you need to make it more efficient, then worry about efficiency. Otherwise leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare `Dates`, your method is efficient one because according to MSDN

*The CompareTo method compares the [Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the current instance and value but ignores their [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone.*

So as it does compare Ticks of two instances of DateTime, so it is the efficient method for comparison.

As a side note, if you want to find interval between DateTime Instances then you can use [DateTime.Subtraction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s85h2eca(v=vs.95).aspx) it will give `TimeSpan` of both DateTime instances. So you can find total difference in their [minutes, hours, days, seconds, milliseconds by using TimeSpan properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 8, 0, 15);
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan interval = dateNow.Subtract(date1);

double totalHours= interval.TotalHours;
double totalMinutes = interval.TotalMinutes;
double totalSeconds= interval.TotalSeconds;
double totalMilliseconds= interval.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 2):

For my opinion, the method you suggested is the most efficiant and accepted way to compare 2 `DateTime` variables in C#, considering you need to take action if the 2 dates are also equal.

**Side note**:

If you only needed to compare the 2 `DateTime` without the equal condition, you could just write:

```
if (currentDateTime < eventDateTime)
    Response.Write("is earlier than Do Nothing");
else
    Response.Write("Time is greater, Trigger Action");
```

which is a bit cleaner and more efficiant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **nested if else statement** as below:

```
if (currentDateTime < eventDateTime)
   Response.Write("is earlier than Do Nothing");
else if(currentDateTime > eventDateTime)
   Response.Write("time is greater, Trigger Action");   
else
   Response.Write("is the same time as: Do Nothing");
```